# Enabling and disabling multitasking within application

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios, multitasking

Currently, my iPad application implements multitasking. However, I would like to offer the user an option to disable multitasking. Is this possible, given the fact that you cannot modify the Info.plist dictionary where the `UIApplicationExistsOnSuspend` key is set?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would a user choose to disable multitasking (i.e. what's the tradeoff)?

Comment: My application plays audio in the background. Sometimes, during my testing phase, I did not want the audio to remain playing when I switched applications, hence the user-friendly option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you *could* set a flag in your application delegate that would simply exit your app when the flag is TRUE within the delegate method `applicationDidEnterBackground:`, like this:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
   BOOL multitasking;
   ...
}
...
@end

@implementation MyAppDelegate

- (void) applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
   if(!multitasking) {
      exit(0);
      return;
   }
   ...
}

...
@end
```

Comment: Does iOS "gently" terminate applications when the user quits? If so, is there any alternative to "exit(0)"?

Comment: @Evan, No, there is no way to "gently" terminate apps in code.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, iOS *does* "gently" terminate applications.  There is a method on UIApplication named _terminateWithStatus: that does this.  However, it's private so there's no (Apple-endorsed) way for *you* to gently terminate an app.  Calling exit() will kill the app, but you're not going to make any friends with it.  So, I believe the answer to your initial questions is no.

Comment: @Adam: I have found `terminateWithSuccess` to be a private method. That seems to do the trick. I do agree with you about using `exit`, as it basically kills my application, which could result in the generation of crash logs.

Comment: @Evan, there is no other (*documented*) way of accomplishing the behavior you described above. Sorry!

Comment: @Evan: Want to make sure you got the gist of Jacob's point: don't use `-terminateWithStatus:`. You'll risk review rejection from Apple. Apple kinda-sorta sanctions the use of `exit` if absolutely necessary: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1561.html

Comment: @quixoto: I attempted to use -terminateWithSuccess, but without success (pardon the pun). Apple rejected it point blank. I ended up removing the option to disable multitasking.

Comment: @Evan Well, if this question is no longer applicable to you, then please either delete it or accept my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Jacob: I did use exit() to terminate the application if it was sent to the background during an initial loading process, so your answer was useful in a way. Thanks.